# Database value comparion using apache-nifi

Tags: postgresql, comparison, apache-nifi

My scenario :

I have two tables. One holding User account details and other has User's email.

User accounts:

```
uid | date
1   | 2019-11-29
2   | 2019-11-20
3   | 2019-11-22
```

User emails :

```
uid | email
1   | sachith@email.com
2   | nalaka@email.com
3   | muha@email.com
```

Admin can check what are accounts created for a specific date. And flow will send all the `uid`s related for that specific date.

Then `nifi` should check `email` table with `uid` and if record is not there for that `uid` then insert to it.

For this, I have used `ExecuteSQL` processor, it takes proper data. But problem is how to get those `uid` and compare with `email` table.

Comment: You need to join the tables - at least in SQL

Comment: unfortunetly, I need to solve this using `apache-nifi` not `sql`. Even if I use `SQL` it should be with `nifi`

Comment: There isn't a way to compare two flowfiles.